# Can I create a service in Automator that will run without having a file selected?

Tags: macos, services, finder, automator

When creating services in automator, the topmost options is "Service receives selected..."
Is there a way to create a service that just works on the currently open finder window, without having a file selected? The reason why this would be nice to have is the following:

I have my unit tests in a directory tree that duplicates that of my source code. I wrote a service using automator, applescript and php that makes it possible to toggle back and forth between the source directories and my test directories. Currently I have to select a file in the directory to activate the service. I would like to be able to just navigate to a folder and activate the service that toggles to the according directory, without having to select a file first (Sometimes there are no files yet!)

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer on the mac [stack exchange](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/104599/can-i-create-a-service-in-automator-that-will-run-without-having-a-file-selected). I guess this question could be deleted, if moderators thought that was a good idea.